# Are Xamarin.Forms custom controls made the same way as WPF/Desktop?

Tags: c#, xaml, xamarin.forms, custom-controls

I have been building desktop apps with C# and WPF since a fairly long time. It's safe to say (it doesn't mean that I'm good at it) that I know how to build custom controls and the style needed, by using this code (abridged):

```
public class HexadecimalBox : ExtendedTextBox
{
    public static readonly DependencyProperty RedProperty = DependencyProperty.Register("Red", typeof(int), typeof(HexadecimalBox), new PropertyMetadata(0, Value_PropertyChanged));

    public int Red
    {
        get => (int)GetValue(RedProperty);
        set => SetValue(RedProperty, value);
    }

    static HexadecimalBox()
    {
        DefaultStyleKeyProperty.OverrideMetadata(typeof(HexadecimalBox), new FrameworkPropertyMetadata(typeof(HexadecimalBox)));
    }

    //Overrides, methods, events registered inside the OnApplyTemplate, etc.
}
```

And this style, also abridged (inside the Themes/Generic.xaml file):

```
<!--HexaDecimalBox Style-->
<Style TargetType="{x:Type n:HexadecimalBox}">
    <Setter Property="MaxLength" Value="9"/>

    <Setter Property="Template">
        <Setter.Value>
            <ControlTemplate TargetType="{x:Type n:HexadecimalBox}">
                <Border Width="{TemplateBinding Width}" Height="{TemplateBinding Height}" MinWidth="{TemplateBinding MinWidth}"
                        BorderBrush="{TemplateBinding BorderBrush}" BorderThickness="{TemplateBinding BorderThickness}"
                        Background="{TemplateBinding Background}" VerticalAlignment="{TemplateBinding VerticalAlignment}"
                        HorizontalAlignment="{TemplateBinding HorizontalAlignment}" SnapsToDevicePixels="True">
                    <ScrollViewer x:Name="PART_ContentHost" Focusable="False" HorizontalScrollBarVisibility="Hidden"
                                  VerticalScrollBarVisibility="Hidden" VerticalContentAlignment="{TemplateBinding VerticalContentAlignment}"/>
                </Border>
            </ControlTemplate>
        </Setter.Value>
    </Setter>

    <Style.Triggers>
        <Trigger Property="IsEnabled" Value="False">
            <Setter Property="Opacity" Value="0.7"/>
        </Trigger>
    </Style.Triggers>
</Style>
```

---

So, I want to learn how to develop a cross-platform app (Android and iOS), with custom controls, basically having the same UI.

I just started reading about it, but I want to be sure that it's possible to create something like that.

How can I achieve that with Xamarin.Forms? Is that possible? How different is it from WPF?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't use `WPF` before but there is a detailed document in official site that helps `WPF` and `Windows Forms developers` to learn mobile app development with `Xamarin`, by cross-referencing their existing knowledge and experience to mobile idioms, and providing examples of porting desktop apps to mobile.

Here is the document:[Cross-Platform for Desktop Developers](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/cross-platform/desktop/).

This part is talking about [UI Controls Comparison](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/cross-platform/desktop/controls/).

> I want to learn how to develop a cross-platform app (Android and
>   iOS), with custom controls, basically having the same UI.

If you use Xamarin.forms, the Android and iOS do share the same UI.

This document is about how to [create controls](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/xamarin-forms/user-interface/) in Xamarin. There are samples there you can look and learn.

Comment: So, do they share the same UI, without needing a custom renderer for each platform? I was reading about it, but I was not sure if it was Forms or an Android/iOS project.

Comment: Oh, yeah looks like there's no need for a custom renderer: https://mindofai.github.io/Creating-Custom-Controls-with-Bindable-Properties-in-Xamarin.Forms/

Comment: Strange is that this one uses a renderer: https://blog.xamarin.com/using-custom-controls-in-xamarin-forms-on-android/

Comment: @NickeManarin Android and iOS project shares UI in Xamarin.forms. However not all controls are same in each platform. You can use custom renderer to customize the appearances and behavior of Xamarin.forms controls on each platform. Also there are some limitations on implementation of controls on each platform, under this situation, you have to use custom renderer to implement the controls. Most of UI are shared.